# Recurring Payments in Magento for Authorize.net

Tags: api, magento-1.8, authorize.net, recurring-billing

Is anyone worked in Magento with Authorize.net for recurring payments. As default "Recurring Profile" is Magento's great feature to Recurring Payments/orders for products but  which has some limitation and designed for nominal items work with  PayPal' Recurring Payment Platform.

I know following things while research for PayPal :
1. Paypal Recurring payments it will create first Recurring profile at PayPal
2. Then it will return reference id to site
3. after that if we want change something then we need to make API call to PayPal like getRecurringProfileDetail etc.

I would like to implement Authorize.net Recurring Profiles feature for Magento Products.

I have confused from where to start or how to implement. I have following questions in mind:

1. How the transactions are happens first time and consecutive transaction automatically ? Is it happen at Magento or at Authorize. net ?

2.How to create order automatically at Magento if transaction successful at authorize.net

3. How can I reuse default "Recurring Profile" core code in my module ? Is it possible. ?
4. Which API I have to use either  SOAP or RESTful ?

Please share your thoughts how to start with this and what are the points I need to keep in mind while working with Recurring Payments with Payment Gateway.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @satish-sojitra - did you found a solution? Anything to share with us? :)

Comment: hi @MatheusJardimB Let me prepare answer and will share here soon. Thanks